# Proving that $HK$ is a subgroup of $ G \iff H \subseteq N(K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

($N(K)$ is the normalizer of $K$)

I proved ($\Leftarrow$). I can't do the other one.
I know the proof that $HK < G \Rightarrow HK=KH$  and this can help.
For what I know, it could also be false, but I feel like I'm missing something not too difficult to do on my own, so, sorry about that and thanks to whoever helps me.

Comment: It's not surprising that you cannot prove it, because it is not true. It's not even true that $H \le N(K)$ or $K \le N(H)$.

Comment: One way to see why this cannot possible be true (and to find a counterexample) is that, since $HK$ is a subgroup, we can replace $G$ by $HK$, so $G=HK$. But since $H$ normalises $K$, then $G$ must normalise $K$.  So we $K$ is normal in $G$, "for free" (with the only hypothesis being that $G=HK$). For an explicit counterexample, consider $G=S_n$ with $H$ and $K$ being $S_{n-1}$ and $C_n$ (the natural copy of each).